# Filtering websites based on specific string

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am currently working on an analysis of urls and want to find urls which match a specific word. Those URLs are in an pandas DataFrame column and I want to filter for specific words in the title of the URL.

What I did so far:

```
data['new'] = data['SOURCEURL'].str.extract("(" + "|".join(filter3) +")", expand=False)
```

The problem about this is that the filter that I apply is an abbreviation ('ecb') which is often also used in the end of a link.

```
http://www.ntnews.com.au/news/national/senate-president-stephen-parry-believes-he-is-a-british-citizen/news-story/b2d3a3442544937f85508135401a3f84?nk=f19e52d2acd9588ecb494c03f21fed8c-1509598074
```

In the last '/'-section. How can I just filter for 'ecb' occurences which occur in textish surrounding? Something like www.xyz.com/news/national/ecb-press-realease/b2dse332313 and which does not extract the occurence of ecb in a hash or something similar as above. Is this possible in an easy way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution is check only in strings before last `/`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SOURCEURL':['http://au/news/nat/cit/news-story/b2ecb',
                                'http://au/news/nat/cit/news-story/b2d88ecb494']})

print (df)
                                       SOURCEURL
0        http://au/news/nat/cit/news-story/b2ecb
1  http://au/news/nat/cit/news-story/b2d88ecb494

filter3 = ['ecb']
df['new'] = (df['SOURCEURL'].str.rsplit('/', 1).str[0]
                            .str.extract("(" + "|".join(filter3) +")", expand=False))
```

Another similar solution:

```
filter3 = ['ecb']
df['new'] = (df['SOURCEURL'].str.extract('(.*)/', expand=False)
                            .str.extract("(" + "|".join(filter3) +")", expand=False))
```

---

```
print (df)
                                       SOURCEURL  new
0        http://au/news/nat/cit/news-story/b2ecb  NaN
1  http://au/news/nat/cit/news-story/b2d88ecb494  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could split the URL into words and filter out all words that are not in an English dictionary? For example using [PyEnchant](https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/):

```
import enchant
d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
filtered_words = [x for x in words if d.check(x)]
```

Comment: I agree, @CalvT븃 - I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach here.  You're probably looking to exclude parameters passed at the end of the URL, which I believe is the only place you'd see either a ? or an =

In this case you can evaluate each split string section as True/False and return the boolean of the sum to get True/False.

```
validation = bool(sum([True if sub in x and "?" not in x and '=' not in x else False for x in url.split('/')]))
```